# JVM terminates with exit code 14 when trying to launch Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've just connected to a machine I never worked on, and tried to run Eclipse there. Unfortunately, I got the error:

> Eclipse:
>   JVM terminated. Exit code=14
>   (my configuration details here)

I guess there's either a problem with my configuration or with that machine's setup, but `Exit code=14` does not give me a lot of information to go on. What does that mean? Where should I start?

I intentionally omitted my configuration details because I'm looking for a general explanation of that exit code, not a specific fix for my configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be related to [bug 9027](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9027): Workbench should check JDK version on startup

You could have an incompatible  (ie too old) JVM: the code 14 has been referenced in this comment as:

> The main launcher detects the JVM terminates with exit code 14. Is the 
>   following message sufficient?

```
Please use a newer VM. Eclipse requires at least 1.3.1.
```

It can also be related with an incompatibility between what is installed on the system and what Eclipse needs when launching: see for instance [this example](http://forums.fedora-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=57236).

Comment: Indeed, a quick check shows the default JVM version on that machine is older than the minimum version required by my Eclipse version, so you appear to be spot-on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @VonC's answer, the Eclipse source code has this to say:

```
// Check to see if we are running with a compatible VM.
// If not, then return exit code "14" which will be recognized
// by the executable and an appropriate message will be displayed
// to the user.
if (!isCompatible())
    System.exit(14);
```

(Source: http://svn.netlabs.org/repos/swt/trunk/src/plugins/org.eclipse.platform/src/org/eclipse/core/launcher/Main.java)

So I suggest checking whether you have a compatible JVM.