# Eclipse doesn't start : JVM terminated. Exit code=14

Tags: eclipse, jvm, java, jvm-crash

Tried searching for a fix couldn't find one!
I am running fedora 17 with :

Eclipse(juno) version

```
eclipse-platform.x86_64                   1:4.2.1-2.fc17
```

A `which java` yields

```
/usr/bin/java
```

so eclipse is using the right one.

A `java -version` yields

```
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.3.3.2.fc17-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

the [Eclipse/Installation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.2_.28Juno.29) page says : 
*A Java 6 JRE/JDK is recommended for Eclipse 4.2.* 
Do i need to downgrade?

---

*I have seen this question :*

[JVM terminates with exit code 14 when trying to launch Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426996/jvm-terminates-with-exit-code-14-when-trying-to-launch-eclipse)

But my configuration seems to be right.

---

Any ideas?

Contents of `eclipse.ini` (path `/etc/eclipse.ini`) :

```
-preventMasterEclipseLaunch
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=//usr/share/eclipse/dropins
```

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage,getDottedValidSourceFiles
 
Here is the complete error message

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=14
/usr/bin/java
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=//usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage,getDottedValidSourceFiles
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v20120814-120055/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib64/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 1f40006
-preventMasterEclipseLaunch
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=//usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/parser/cpp/semantics/CPPTemplates,instantiateTemplate
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/pdom/dom/cpp/PDOMCPPLinkage,addBinding
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/editor/codecompletion/revisited/PythonPathHelper,isValidSourceFile
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/python/pydev/ui/filetypes/FileTypesPreferencesPage,getDottedValidSourceFiles
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of your eclipse.ini file?

Comment: @asgoth have added the contents of eclipse.ini in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure about IcedTea, but it works fine with Oracle 1.7 java.

Comment: And if you can check log. (See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F).

Comment: Mine doesn't have those '-XX:CompileCommand'. Probably not the cause, but try to remove them. But first, make a backup of your eclipse.ini.

Comment: @asgoth on a hunch I removed the first line `-preventMasterEclipseLaunch` and eclipse seems to be working! if I google `-preventMasterEclipseLaunch` I get 0 search results!

Comment: @dbrank0 on a hunch I removed the first line -preventMasterEclipseLaunch and eclipse seems to be working! if I google -preventMasterEclipseLaunch I get 0 search results!

Comment: Well, i was close :) Mostly such errors have a cause in eclipse.ini

Comment: See same issue with jdk 1.6 while running eclipse Mars (& PyCharm also) under Ubuntu 14.04. It works with jdk 1.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what resolved the problem :

on a hunch(all the .ini files that I had seen on the net did not have the first line. And the meaning(English) of the words involved in the first line seemed weird), I removed the first line

```
-preventMasterEclipseLaunch
```

and eclipse seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for all the trouble that I caused by introducing this flag, but... you should really know what you're doing if you want to start Eclipse as root, because:

- Eclipse is a plugin based app and runs all plugins no matter what. Working as root with IDEs is generally NOT a good idea.
- Eclipse writes a lot of configuration details in the root filesystem - your installation is no longer verifiable by RPM, Eclipse installation is effectively broken - depending on what you have
  installed you may not be able to install any other Eclipse plugin.